# Find contact normal for sensor in Box2d 2.1a

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d, collision-detection

I am extending the `b2ContactListener` to find out the normals of my collisions. However, every time I get a contact with a sensor, the normal is always 0,0. How do I get the normal if one of the bodies is a sensor?

```
override public virtual function BeginContact( contact : b2Contact ) : void
{
    var normal : b2Vec = contact.GetFixtureA.GetBody().GetContactList().contact.GetManifold().m_localPlaneNormal;

    // normal is always 0,0 if it is a sensor.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The normal (and anything else in the contact manifold) is only necessary to calculate what kind of collision response should be applied to push two fixtures apart when they overlap. Since sensors don't have any collision response, this information is not needed and therefore not calculated for them.

One way you could get a normal without the usual collision response is to revert your fixture back to being a non-sensor, and in the PreSolve callback just do contact->SetEnabled(false) for every contact involving that fixture.